# How to set path for files in monaco editor?

Tags: html, monaco-editor

This is a snippet of html code in a `test.html` file.

```js
<script src="monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script>
 require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'monaco-editor/min/vs' }});
 require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
  var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
   value: [
    'function x() {',
    '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
    '}'
   ].join('\n'),
   language: 'javascript'
  });
 });
</script>
```

this is a file tree on my system.

`ide
 ├── cpp14
 │   ├── test.html
 ├── monaco
     └── node_modules
         ├── monaco-editor
         └── test.html`

I copied `test.html` file from `monaco/node_moules/`  to `cpp14`

And changed all the paths in `cpp14/test.html` to

```js
<script src="ide/monaco/node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script>
 require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'ide/monaco/node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs' }});
 require(['ide/monaco/node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
  var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
   value: [
    'function x() {',
    '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
    '}'
   ].join('\n'),
   language: 'javascript'
  });
    });
```

This is not working and I think there is error in setting path of those files in the snippet.
How to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try aliasing it:

```
require.config({
    paths:{
         'ide/monaco/node_modules/test.html': 'ide/cpp14/test.html'
          'vs': '...'
    }
});
```